# setup git to ignore index.php in root folder only and not all index.php files in subfolders

Tags: git

I have .gitignore as

```
index.php
protected/config/
```

I wanted to ignore only index.php in root but git is ignoring all files with index.php in sub-folders as well. 
How I can modify .gitignore to ignore only specific index.php file and not all files with name index.php

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to ignore it?

Comment: I am using different settings on my local machine and server. It is just including files from other libraries. My local machine is windows but server is opensuse and third party libraries are on diff paths. But I need all index.php files in views/ .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `/index.php` in your `.gitignore`

Comment: This is correct. If the path contains any slashes anywhere, it matches against the full path of the file. So `/index.php` will only match the file `index.php` at the root. If the path contains zero slashes, it's matched against the filename instead, so `index.php` will match a file named `index.php` at any depth.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, i did use `/index.php` but any changes i do for this file on root path is tracked anyway.